# Add number to row if condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with some diagnostic test data.  Here is a small sample:

```
tibble::tribble(
     ~TP, ~FN, ~FP, ~TN,
      37,   5,  49,  10,
      28,   3,   0,  27,
       0,  18,  12, 106,
      18,   0,   0,  40,
      18,   0,  10,  30
     )
```

Some of the counts for the diagnostic tests are 0.  In tests with a 0 count, I would like to add 0.5 to all cell counts.  Here is my desired output

```
tibble::tribble(
     ~TP, ~FN, ~FP, ~TN,
      37,   5,  49,  10,
      28.5,   3.5,   0.5,  27.5,
      0.5,  18.5,  12.5, 106.5,
      18.5,   0.5,   0.5,  40.5,
      18.5,   0.5,  10.5,  30.5
     )
```

Note, the first row did not change because all the counts were larger than 0.  However, each remaining row changed since there was at least one zero in each of those rows.

How can I perform this with dplyr?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply and check for 0's

```
t(apply(df,1,function(x) if(0 %in% x) return(x+0.5) else return(x)))
```

or if we insist on dplyr,

```
a%>%
  t()%>%
  data.frame(check.names = F) %>%
  rownames_to_column()%>%
  mutate_if(function(col) any(0 %in% col),function(col) col+0.5)%>%
  column_to_rownames()%>%
  t()%>%
  data.frame()
```

some things are just easier in base R.

```
 TP   FN   FP    TN
[1,] 37.0  5.0 49.0  10.0
[2,] 28.5  3.5  0.5  27.5
[3,]  0.5 18.5 12.5 106.5
[4,] 18.5  0.5  0.5  40.5
[5,] 18.5  0.5 10.5  30.5
```